# How do class-based views work in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to have an understanding to reason about Django + DRF.

I'm following along the tutorial on the [Django Rest Framework site](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/)

Consider the SnippetList class in views.py:

```
class SnippetList(APIView):
"""
List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
"""
def get(self, request, format=None):
    snippets = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

I'm used to JavasCript and to a more imperative way of doing things and it feels that there is a lot of magic here since I'm not explicitly instantiating any classes nor calling any methods.

So, my question is, what happens when I request this view? How can I reason about the steps and the process?

I visit the endpoint in http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/ to get a list of all the snippets and what is the cascade of events thereafter?

How is the /snippets/ query parameter passed to the view class?

I realise it's it might not be a specific enough question but I'm trying to disentangle the magic happening behind the scenes.

Comment: Are you asking for all the steps taken from Django receiving the request to the get method on your class being called? There are quite a few steps in that process (wsgi, url resolver, middleware, the view class itself) can you be more specific which part you are interested in?

Comment: I think the view class itself would the most useful thing right now.

Comment: The simplified answer is that Django calls the `dispatch` method on your class with the request and any url params, the base `dispatch` method then calls the method on the class that matches the lowercase HTTP method ('GET', 'POST', etc.) and passes it the same arguments. I often use this website to see the internals https://www.cdrf.co/3.13/rest_framework.views/APIView.html#dispatch